# Git remove subtree or change directory of subtree

Tags: android, git, git-subtree

I am trying to synchronize with updates for my subtree by doing

`git pull -s subtree react master`

but the whole repo is copied into wrong folder not the one I mention while adding a new repository as a subtree.

How can I remove subtree or change directory of subtree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To update a subtree checked out in `[directory]`, I would use :

```
git subtree pull -P [directory] react master
```

---

- renaming the subtree folder from `path1` to `path2` :

  ```
  git mv path1 path2
  ```

  and use `path2` in all subsequent `git subtree` commands
- deleting the subtree at `path1` :

  ```
  git rm -rf path1
  ```

Comment: @KatyColins it's "deleting the subtree at...". I tested. It works

Comment: @LeoNguyen but this doesn't remove the commits, right? The folder is removed but the commits from the subtree are still there

Comment: @KennetCeleste : yes